# Issues with FluentValidation implementation for .NET 7 Web API application

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation, .net-7.0

I have a .NET 7 web api with multiple controllers. Right now I am using repository pattern in the implementation. I wanted to implement generic validation pipeline similar to the one : https://code-maze.com/cqrs-mediatr-fluentvalidation/ for all the action methods in the project.

Here goes the code details :

**ReqValMiddleware.cs**

```
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Throw;

namespace Infrastructure.Middlewares;
internal sealed class ReqValMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        context.ThrowIfNull("HttpContext cannot be null.");
        if (context.Request.Method == "POST" || context.Request.Method == "PUT")
        {
            var requestBodyType = GetRequestBodyType(context);
            if (requestBodyType != null)
            {
                var validatorType = typeof(IValidator<>).MakeGenericType(requestBodyType);
                var validator = context.RequestServices.GetService(validatorType);
                if (validator != null)
                {
                    var request = await context.Request.ReadFromJsonAsync(requestBodyType);
                    var validationResult = await ((dynamic)validator).ValidateAsync(request);
                    if (!validationResult.IsValid)
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 400; // Bad Request
                        await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(validationResult.Errors);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        await next(context);
    }

    private Type GetRequestBodyType(HttpContext context)
    {
        var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
        if (endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor>()is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor controllerActionDescriptor)
        {
            var parameter = controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetParameters().FirstOrDefault();
            if (parameter != null)
                return parameter.ParameterType;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;
using System.Reflection;

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddFluentValidation();

        // Register all validators from the assembly containing the Startup class
        services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // Register the ValidationMiddleware as a scoped service
        services.AddScoped<ReqValMiddleware>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseMiddleware<ValidationMiddleware>();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

**UserDto.cs**

```
using FluentValidation;

public class UserDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class UserDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<UserDto>
{
    public UserDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(dto => dto.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Name is required.");
        RuleFor(dto => dto.Age).InclusiveBetween(18, 100).WithMessage("Age must be between 18 and 100.");
    }
}
```

**UserController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateUser([FromBody] UserDto userDto)
    {
        // The request will be validated by the middleware before reaching this action.
        // If the validation fails, the middleware will return 400 Bad Request with validation errors.

        // Process the validated DTO and create a user.
        // For demonstration purposes, we'll just return the created user as a response.
        return Ok(userDto);
    }
}
```

With the above code I am getting a compile time error in the ReqValMiddleware.cs:

```
'HttpResponse' has no applicable method named 'WriteAsJsonAsync' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.
```

Line of Code with error: `await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(validationResult.Errors);`

I have commented the above line of code and tried to debug it and came across below runtime error :

```
The best overloaded method match for 'FluentValidation.AbstractValidator<UserDto>.ValidateAsync(UserDto, System.Threading.CancellationToken)' has some invalid arguments
```

Line of Code with error:

```
var validationResult = await ((dynamic)validator).ValidateAsync(request);
```

Both the issues are happening at the ReqValMiddleware level

I'm seeking insights and suggestions on how to properly handle this issue. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st issue, you can't pass the value which is a `dynamic` type to the extension method.

To resolve this issue, you can cast the `validationResult` as the `ValidationResult` type.

```cs
using FluentValidation.Results;

var validationResult = await validator.ValidateAsync(request) as ValidationResult;
```

For the 2nd issue which is the `RuntimeBinderException`, you should create the instance and cast the request body as generic type in runtime.

```cs
dynamic request = Activator.CreateInstance(requestBodyType);
request = Convert.ChangeType(await context.Request.ReadFromJsonAsync(requestBodyType), requestBodyType);
```

Comment: [Similar Demo with Mocked HttpContext @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kRiGXT)